# Android wake up mobile connection / accept data after sleep

Tags: android, connection, gsm

I have a problem with data connection over gsm network.
When device sleeps cannot interact with server.Seems mobile network turns off.When turn on display mobile connection turn on and sends requests again automatically.

In wifi mode I use WifiLock but cannot found approach like this for mobile radio/mobile data connection.

Regards

Comment: How are you communicating with the server? Is the communication happening in a Service?
To properly answer this question, we need some code to look at.

Comment: The communication is in service which check for new data.And if has new data shows notification.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AlarmManager to schedule your data checks. Setting the AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP alarm type will cause the device to wakeup every time the alarm goes off (and thus your service is started). This should get you the data connection you need.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// Start every 30 seconds
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, pendingIntent);
```

See:

- [PendingIntent.getService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29)
- [AlarmManager.setRepeating()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) to keep the CPU / radios on whilst the screen is off.
Use with care.